# Laravel,end of migrations relationship at some time

Tags: laravel, database-migration

hi I have the following question. In laravel I created 2 tables, apartments and sponsors with many to many relationships. Depending on the plan chosen, the sponsors have a variable duration that I valued in the pivot table(start_time and end_time). I would need the relationship between the apartment and the sponsor to end automatically after the sponsorship period has ended(when the date and day coincide with the end_time of the pivot table). How could I do such a thing? I thought about using `detach` but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You could add a where statement to your relationship, leave the relationship in the pivot but render it useless?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to look at these problems from different perspectives. Like the two comments mention, you could use [Job Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) In windows or cron jobs in linux systems.
The next option is to create another field in your pivot which is something like “active”. So this will be a boolean and will always return a true or false. Now you can combine task scheduling and using a custom artisan command, you can keep checking if the sponsor expired and if it did expire, set the active field to false. 
And to top it all, when you get your data, simply filter your query. I do not know how your code looks like but here is a sample code of a pivot and how I would have filtered it (not tested):

```
//Here active null assumes it is false value. Active 1 assumes it is true. So the active field will be nullable
$myQuery = Sponsor::with([‘apartments’ => function($q) {
$q->where(‘active’, null)->get();
}])->get();
//The apartments is assumed to be the pivot relationship in your sponspor model
```

This is just a simple example of how you could chain and query a relationship, whether be a pivot or any other table, you can do custom queries within like mentioned above. Something along the lines should work in your case